# How do you mock process.platform in jasmine tests?

Tags: node.js, mocking, jasmine

How do you mock process.platform using jasmine specs?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty()` to set value of `process.platform` in `beforeAll` and then reset it to original in `afterAll` after tests are finished.

If you print of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(process, "platform")` to get `descriptor` configuration of `platform.process` in node.js console then you will get following:

```
{ value: 'darwin',
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true }
```

As you can see, value of `process.platform` is not writable (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information) so you can't set it using assignment operator. but you can override it using `Object.defineProperty`.

Jasmine Example

```
describe('test process platform', function(){
    beforeAll(function(){
       this.originalPlatform = process.platform;
       Object.defineProperty(process, 'platform', {  
         value: 'MockOS'
       });
    });

    it(/*test*/);

    ....

    it(/*test*/);

    afterAll(function(){
       Object.defineProperty(process, 'platform', {  
         value: this.originalPlatform
       });
    });
});
```

**[Object.defineProperty() Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)**

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the thorough explanation through `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`! I'm also having an issue with mocking path.sep / path.separator, even though it's writeable. Any ideas there?

Comment: if `path.sep` is writable then you can simply set it using assignment operator `path.sep = '#'`.  i am able to do it on my machine.

Comment: Note: For some reason something like this has stopped working for me recently, but this still works. Thanks jad-panda :)

Comment: This does not work for me using node20: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: platform`